# Include missing column-values between two Indexs when a GroupBy is run on a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that was GroupBy lineOfBuiness, stream and status and a count column was created. I am trying to get the status column to be consistent in terms of the number of row between to two lineOfBusiness slices (Commodities and Equities Derivatives below).

For example: If you notice in Commodities Slice, there is a status called 
'Prioritized for Analysis' that does not exist in Equity Derivatives.

Another example: There is a slice 'Prioritized fro Development' in the Equities Derivatives that does not exist in Commodities. Is there anyway to programatically create the missing statuses and assign a count 0 or NaN.

```
lineOfBusiness            stream            status                             count
    Commodities               BOW/Project       Closed                             2   
                                                In Analysis                        4   
                                                In Solution                        3   
                                                Open                              28   
                                                Prioritized for Analysis           1   
                                                Tech Execution                     7  



Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       In Analysis                        2   
                                            In Solution                        1   
                                            Open                               4   
                                            Prioritized for Development        1   
                                            Tech Execution                     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `unstack` will produce a column for every unique value in the index level being unstacked.  The number of columns will be greater than or equal to the number of unique values in the index level.  Any level value not present for one or more other levels will be filled with `np.nan` unless otherwise specified with a `fill_value` parameter.

Using `stack` will reshape a column level by appending it to an index level.  To save space, by default, `stack` drops `np.nan` rows unless specified with the `dropna=False` parameter.

***[`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)***
***[`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)***

```
df.unstack('status').stack('status', dropna=False)
# equivalent code if `status` is in last level
# df.unstack().stack(dropna=False)

                                                            count
lineOfBusiness     stream      status                            
Commodities        BOW/Project Closed                         2.0
                               In Analysis                    4.0
                               In Solution                    3.0
                               Open                          28.0
                               Prioritized for Analysis       1.0
                               Prioritized for Development    NaN
                               Tech Execution                 7.0
Equity Derivatives BOW/Project Closed                         NaN
                               In Analysis                    2.0
                               In Solution                    1.0
                               Open                           4.0
                               Prioritized for Analysis       NaN
                               Prioritized for Development    1.0
                               Tech Execution                 1.0
```

Or

```
df.unstack('status', fill_value=0).stack('status')
# equivalent code if `status` is in last level
# df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
                                                        count
lineOfBusiness     stream      status                            
Commodities        BOW/Project Closed                           2
                               In Analysis                      4
                               In Solution                      3
                               Open                            28
                               Prioritized for Analysis         1
                               Prioritized for Development      0
                               Tech Execution                   7
Equity Derivatives BOW/Project Closed                           0
                               In Analysis                      2
                               In Solution                      1
                               Open                             4
                               Prioritized for Analysis         0
                               Prioritized for Development      1
                               Tech Execution                   1
```

---

***setup code***
*making it easy for others to try*

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

txt = """lineOfBusiness            stream            status                             count
    Commodities               BOW/Project       Closed                             2   
    Commodities               BOW/Project       In Analysis                        4   
    Commodities               BOW/Project       In Solution                        3   
    Commodities               BOW/Project       Open                              28   
    Commodities               BOW/Project       Prioritized for Analysis           1   
    Commodities               BOW/Project       Tech Execution                     7  
Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       In Analysis                        2   
Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       In Solution                        1   
Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       Open                               4   
Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       Prioritized for Development        1   
Equity Derivatives        BOW/Project       Tech Execution                     1   
"""

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=[0, 1, 2])
```